# Python Selenium not giving out expected results

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I want to scrape the Github trendings page and came up with this code. For some reason, it wouldnt work properly and instead gave out some other session code. Any idea why?
Here is my code -

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup



driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://github.com/trending')
content_element = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/div[4]/main/div[3]/div/div[2]/article[1]/h1/a")

for element in content_element:  
  print(element)

driver.close()
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extract all trending repositories with `beautifulsoup` using this example:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://github.com/trending'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

for a in soup.select('article h1 a'):
    print('{:<50} {}'.format(a.get_text(strip=True, separator=' '), 'https://github.com' + a['href']))
```

Prints:

```
cli / cli                                          https://github.com/cli/cli
gnebbia / kb                                       https://github.com/gnebbia/kb
schollz / croc                                     https://github.com/schollz/croc
onevcat / Kingfisher                               https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher
moby / moby                                        https://github.com/moby/moby
matterport / Mask_RCNN                             https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN
google / googletest                                https://github.com/google/googletest
FreeCAD / FreeCAD                                  https://github.com/FreeCAD/FreeCAD
iamadamdev / bypass-paywalls-chrome                https://github.com/iamadamdev/bypass-paywalls-chrome
vuejs / vue-next                                   https://github.com/vuejs/vue-next
microsoft / onefuzz                                https://github.com/microsoft/onefuzz
twintproject / twint                               https://github.com/twintproject/twint
lyhue1991 / eat_tensorflow2_in_30_days             https://github.com/lyhue1991/eat_tensorflow2_in_30_days
snakers4 / silero-models                           https://github.com/snakers4/silero-models
hediet / vscode-debug-visualizer                   https://github.com/hediet/vscode-debug-visualizer
tannerlinsley / react-query                        https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-query
proxysu / windows                                  https://github.com/proxysu/windows
mozilla / send                                     https://github.com/mozilla/send
jaywcjlove / linux-command                         https://github.com/jaywcjlove/linux-command
material-shell / material-shell                    https://github.com/material-shell/material-shell
iamkun / dayjs                                     https://github.com/iamkun/dayjs
swisskyrepo / PayloadsAllTheThings                 https://github.com/swisskyrepo/PayloadsAllTheThings
TheCherno / Hazel                                  https://github.com/TheCherno/Hazel
HeroTransitions / Hero                             https://github.com/HeroTransitions/Hero
pytorch / pytorch                                  https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch
```